# iphone interface builder

Tags: iphone, interface-builder

I am new to iphone and getting problem i have defined actions but i am not able to see it in File owners window so that i can connect it, and secondly i have added images to resources folders but they are not available in dropdown for imageview, i am getting this problem from couple of weeks when i re-install the sdk is working fine for first time but whenever i re-launch the sdk i am not getting the above mentioned problem, please help.

Answer (score 0):

Irfan, are you creating actions in the correct class? the file owner's class? Might be possible those actions are being written in other classes so not showing in file owner's inspector window.

When we add images in resource folder.... by adding files in project..... those changes will be reflected only in  those xibs which are opened completely after adding images........
so, if the changes does not reflect,it does not shows image names in drop-down, just close that xib completely or close the interface builder than reopen the xib in which you wish to add images. I hope it will work...

Thanks,

Comment: thank you for your feedback, i am creating the actions/methods in correct class, when i re-install the sdk it works but after a few re-launch it stop working. second the images, i even restart but not able to see the images on re-install it works fine, guess both actions and images have same problem.

Comment: If this is the case then..... when you are in interface builder go  in File and select Read Class Files  and locate your File Owner file. May be changes are not reflected . This will solve our first problem.